# SQL Server query help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try the following query, zero rows are affected. Can someone help me to fix this?

```
UPDATE PLAN 
SET PLANID = (SELECT PLANID FROM MODE WHERE [NAME]='Sam')
WHERE CUSTOMERID IN (SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM ENTITYCUSTOMER WHERE EMPID = 707)
```

`(SELECT PLANID FROM MODE WHERE [NAME]='Sam')` will return a single code

`(SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM ENTITYCUSTOMER WHERE EMPID = 707)` may return multiple values.

Please help need a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Obvious question: when you run SELECT CustomerId FROM EntityCustomer WHERE EmpId=707, do you actually get any results? And if so, can you see records in the Plan table with those values in the CustomerId field?

Comment: No errors? Just zero rows affected? Both subqueries have results? Does PLAN table has rows that match the results of the second subquery?

Comment: Also check if there is only one Sam in the MODE table.

Comment: Please let us know if you get any results with this query.. `select p.* from plan p inner join ENTITYCUSTOMER ec on p.CUSTOMERID = ec.CUSTOMERID where ec.EMPID = 707`

Comment: @patmortech: Yes, I actually get results for that. And, again yes.

Comment: @dpp: Yes, no errors and zero rows are affected. Both the sub queries returns values. And, yes there is only one Sam in the table.

Comment: @Murtaza: query executed successfully but no rows displayed

Comment: Based on @Murtaza's query result (no records), that means you do not have any records in the Plan table that have the same customerID as the customer record with EMPID=707. Which would be why no rows were affected.

Comment: @patmortech is right. Just to check i gave Saravanan Mageswaran this query, since you do not have any records to update. your query is giving you right message "zero rows are affected".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PLANID FROM MODE WHERE [NAME]='Sam'
```

The 'MODE' table must not be keyed on PLANID; so it can't bind a specific value to the update. One option is to create a cursor, and read the correct value with which to update. Another is to do this in whatever client code language you are using (presumably a .net langugage?)

Comment: If it didn't return any value, it would set PLANID to null, or if PlanID did not allow nulls, you'd get an error. Either way, that subquery would not have an impact on how many rows the update statement affects.

Comment: Right, but you can't update a single column with (possible) multiple values.

Comment: He said in his post that it only returned one value. And you would get an error if it tried to return multiple records.